# gcc: error: –version: No such file or directory

Tags: command-line, gcc

I'm under Ubuntu 16.04. When I run

```
gcc –version
```

I get:

```
gcc: error: –version: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
```

However

```
dpkg -l | grep gcc | awk '{print $2}'
```

gives me:

```
gcc
gcc-4.9
gcc-4.9-base:amd64
gcc-5
gcc-5-base:amd64
gcc-6-base:amd64
gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0
libcaca0:amd64
libgcc-4.9-dev:amd64
libgcc-5-dev:amd64
libgcc1:amd64
libpackagekit-glib2-16:amd64
libunity-action-qt1:amd64
libwebrtc-audio-processing-0:amd64
qtchooser
qtdeclarative5-unity-action-plugin:amd64
```

Comment: try: gcc  --version

Comment: Looks like you copy-pasted the command and the two hyphens `--` got replaced by an [en dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash)

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing is because you have copied an en dash, not a normal hyphen.  An en dash won't work here, and that's why you get the error.

This is the typical output on a 16.04 machine when you run with `--version` (the correct notation):

```
% gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

(This may differ slightly on your system - I run multiple GCC versions for different tasks, but the point is that an en dash doesn't work, but two standard hyphens will)